# VSS to TFS Migration Administrator Password Error

Tags: migration, visual-sourcesafe-2005, tfs-migration

I am currently using `VSSConverter.exe` to migrate a Visual SourceSafe 2005 database to TFS 2010.

However, whenever I try to begin the `analyze` process I get an error as follows:

```
Initializing...
VSS administrator password:************
TF60012:  The password is incorrect.
```

I can confirm the password is accurate (and works when I use the Visual SourceSafe Administration Tool).

As such, does anyone have any idea why `VSSConverter.exe` is not accepting the admin password?

As a thought, is there a way to specify the admin details in `VSSConverter.exe`'s `settings.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems the password was reset at some stage, and while that successfully allowed the Visual SourceSafe Administration Tool to connect, it appears there must be some reference to the old password somewhere (fortunately the SysAdmin recalled the old password).

Once the old password was entered, things continued as expected.

If anyone has further info/experience with the issue though, it'd be interesting to find out why the Admin Tool can connect, but `VSSConverter` requires the old password.